# Convolutional Model result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was working with a convolutional model and this is my code

```
#Import the necessary libraries
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np 
import os
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cats_and_dogs_filtered/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cats_and_dogs_filtered/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary')

history = model.fit(
      train_generator,
      epochs=15,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      )

test_image = image.load_img('single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (150,150))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = model.predict(test_image)
print(train_generator.class_indices)
print(result)
```

The class_indices was  {'cats': 0, 'dogs': 1}
The output of result was  **[[5.916551e-06]]**

While sigmoid gives us a value between 0 and 1, and this value being near 0 indicates the class it belongs to, I have always gotten a value of 1 or 0 output in the case of binary classification before (Just learning about augmentation). I can not find appropriate resources on google about this answer so I want to know whether I am not doing something wrong here and that I should probably add a threshold as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, It was my misunderstanding. The value closer to 0 or 1 shows the class it belongs to so adding a threshold of 0.5> or <0.5 was needed.